# Symbolicate crash logs in xcode 4.3 doesn't work if the app name contains an apostrophe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.3, symbolicatecrash

My app icon name (the name of the app in the springboard) is like: My'App

When I see crash logs in the organizer they are not symbolicated. If I delete the ' of the name (like MyApp) then they are symbolicated.

Does anybody have the same issue?
Is there a way to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same problem - did you find a way to symbolicate an app with an apostrophe in its name?

Answer (score 0):

Try create a .sh file who do:

1) rename your app name to true

2) do a symbolicate commands

And for run him do

```
sudo bash Symbolicate.sh
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you said